# Powerpoint editor and player web-based

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, powerpoint

I need to develop in ASP.NET or in SilverLight a web-based editor and a web-based player for PowerPoint presentation. Are there any components I can use to do this?

Comment: Coding it yourself is going to be a major project and is not answerable in a reasonable way.

Comment: Powerpoint has millions of lines of code and hundreds of thousands of man hours of development into it.  It's not something that can be reasonably asked of any one person to re-implement in any real time frame.  You *may* be able to buy something that would let you view it, but editing is going to be nearly impossible.

Comment: Ok! But I don't want to develop PowerPoint online! I need small editor with basse funtionality. That's all.

Comment: And about player...maybe already exist...I want just to buy it.

Comment: does the below work for you? if so, you can select the hollow checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 3):

There are no good web-based editors for PowerPoint, other than [Office Web Apps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/using-office-web-apps-in-sharepoint-HA010380116.aspx). For that, you need SharePoint 2010. Note that this is intended for internal organizations - not for the public web.

Creating one yourself would be a ton of work. However, if you just needed basic editing of certain parts (in particular, textual), you could work with the Open XML SDK to create something workable. This article may give you a good start: [Creating a PresentationML Document through a browser interface](http://openxmldeveloper.org/archive/2006/08/24/559.aspx).

For web-based players, there are a few options:

- **Silverlight**: [Convexion](http://www.erain.com/Products/Convexion/Default.asp) by
  Electronic Rain. It's not the best of
  players/converters, but currently
  better than the rest
  ([PPTX2Silverlight](http://pptx2silverlight.codeplex.com/),
  [Powerlight](http://www.conaito.com/powerlight-powerpoint-xps-silverlight-converter.asp), etc.)
- **Flash**: [Articulate](http://www.articulate.com/), [Adobe
  Presenter](http://www.adobe.com/products/presenter/) and [iSpring Free](http://www.ispringfree.com/)
  are all good options.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://280slides.com/

Not sure whether you can run it on your own server though.